# Android studio 2D Map Navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, dictionary, navigation, 2d

i'd like to know what to use a create a 2D navigation map on android studio , like a map of a store in which you can navigate , see your position etc ...

For example : You wanna know where the milk is , you open the app , you see your position on the map (Maybe a picture from top-side view) and which way to go , it's just like a game , like fortnite, cs , lol , or any other game with a map

So i've read on other topics that there is some game engines like AndEngine , but i don't think they satisfy my needs.

And when i search for it , i only get "Google Map" suggestions

It is the first time i work on such project , so i need your help guys , thank you very much